# How to split a string value in football database using R

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr

I am fairly new to the R world but I am in the process of self teaching. The issue I am running into for my dataset is a challenging character value. Basically I have a column of data that looks like this "Won Speed, E.J. IND LB for $810,000". I would like to split this into several new columns so that each part of this string is in a new column.

So far I have done this:

```
str<-strsplit(fa_aw_2019$Transaction," ")
```

which returns a data.frame showing below:

```
str        list[28]          List of length of 28
[[1]]       character[7]     'Won' 'Speed,' 'EJ.' 'IND' 'LB' 'for' '$810,000'
```

The other tricky point is that I have 842 observations to do this for....

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide any sample data by using `dput(df)`? It makes it much easier to find a solution when there is a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strsplit` creates nested lists.

You can have a look at `stringr::str_split` or `stringr::str_split_fixed`. They have an argument `simplify = TRUE` that returns character vector. The second function should be preferred if you know that all your characters to split have the same number of words

You also have an option with `tstrsplit` in `data.table`. That's a very efficient solution. In that case,

```r
library(data.table)
df <- copy(fa_aw_2019)
df[, strsplit(Transaction," ")]

# OR IF YOU HAVE SAME NUMBER OF WORDS
df[, strsplit(Transaction," ", fixed = TRUE)]
```

Be careful if some observations have more words than others because you won't be able to use `fixed` so can end up with messy data (which is not the case with lists)